# How do I transfer my own domain name to Wordpress

Tags: domain

I have had a Google blogger blog for several years and I have a domain name purchased through Go Daddy. The blog itself is hosted by Google, free. So my domain name is www.Wordchipper.com It's probably a re-direct from Go Daddy so that when a user types in the above address, it gets them to me without the "blogspot.com"

What I want to know is if I switch to Wordpresses's free blog service, can I use my Go Daddy registered www.Wordchipper.com or do I have to pay Wordpress for that? I don't have to pay Google now. This is a stumbling block on moving to Wordpress.

Need a clear answer to this..thank you...Larry

Comment: Close-voting as off-topic. This is not specific to self-hosted WordPress. If you're looking for WP.com help, visit: http://en.support.wordpress.com/

Answer (score 1):

> Mapping a domain you already own costs $13.00 per domain, per year.

http://en.support.wordpress.com/domains/map-existing-domain/